# Is there a way to choice a specific one between fragments as extra data?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Now I am making a small android-app.

And I face a problem.

[image]

It is a structure of my app. The red arrow is a problem.

I can go to ConfigActivity, But now I only can go HomeFramgent not ConfigFragment.

How can it be possible?

Is there a way to choice a specific one between fragments in that arrow?

Sorry for my poor English. Give me some advice to solve this problem please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey You can switch to your fragments of HomeActivity which uses Tab layout like this:

```
   TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
   TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(someIndex);
   tab.select();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the current fragment's sate, check it in onResume() method of MainActivity and go to the needed fragment (last opened).

*Advice* - use only fragments. Left only Main activity for the whole app.
Why you shouls use fragments instead of activities - https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/activities-or-fragments-a-little-sharing-c1ddc1041f79

Comment: I'm an beginner. I don't want to make excuses, but now I'm not sure what should I do, even after reading that post. But thank for your advice. I will think about that and make a better application. Thank you.